# How to properly add time to Firestore & compare it to a future timestamp to determine a subscription expiry date swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

What is the proper way to save time to Firestore & how do I get back the values to compare them & determine if a subscription is expired?

I am currently using:

1. Apple's date & components to save expiry date
2. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to save purchased date &

```
let now = Date()
let components = DateComponents(day:45)
var futureTimeStamp: TimeInterval = 0.0
        
if let future = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: now, wrappingComponents: false) {
       print(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: future, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium))
            
       futureTimeStamp = future.timeIntervalSince1970
      
} else {
       print("Can't create date")
}

self.db.collection("users/subscriptions").document("\(subscriptionDoc)").setData([
    "product" : "Grade1",
    "dateExpiry" : futureTimeStamp,
    "datePurchased" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    "userId" : userId
])
```

The Firebase time is represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond in UTC Epoch time. (ex. Jun 3, 2022 at 12:59:43 PM is 1654275583.406064)

In Firestore I see:

1. dateExpiry as a number &
2. datePurchased as a timestamp:

[image]

However, when I get the document I return the following

Optional([
"dateExpiry": 1654275583.406064,
"datePurchased": 
])

As you can see the datePurchased from serverTimeStamp() is null even though there is a date in the document on Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

The `Calendar` class has lots of methods to do "calendrical calculations" on dates.

I suggest using the function `date(byAdding:to:wrappingComponents:)`:

```
import Foundation

let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
let components = DateComponents(day:45)
if let future = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: now, wrappingComponents: false) {
    print(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: future, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium))
} else {
    print("Can't create date")
}
```

That outputs the following:

```
May 21, 2022 at 6:36:32 AM
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to make the now property equal to the date from the serverTimeStamp I set when the item is purchased & then add my time interval. The idea is to have the times be from the same source incase the user travels & the device time is different that the Firebase time

Comment: Sure there is. Edit your question to provide information about the format of the Firebase time provided to you. Is it in number of seconds/milliseconds since the UNIX Epoch date? A date string? Some other format?

Comment: As requested I updated the question for better clarity

Comment: Ok, the dateExpiry is numeric, and is the number of nanoseconds since the UNIX epoch date. That will be easy enough to convert to a date. (Divide the value by 1,000,000 and use the resulting value in a call to `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)`

Comment: I am still not clear on the format you're getting for the `datePurchased`. You said "as a timestamp". What does that mean? Is it a date string?

Comment: Okay, so let's say I recorded both datePurchased & dateExpiry in nanoseconds. How could I code a comparison to see if the current date is beyond the dateExpiry? Also, what if the user changes their device current time then how can I protect against this?